# ASP .NET Core OpenIdConnect Access Token not a valid JWT

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, azure-ad-graph-api

Using .Net Core 2.2 I encounter this issue where the TokenResponseReceivedContext doesn't contain a valid JWT access token:

```
public override Task TokenResponseReceived(TokenResponseReceivedContext context)
        {
            // context.TokenEndpointResponse.AccessToken is not a valid JWT but 
            // context.TokenEndpointResponse.IdToken is and 
            // context.TokenEndpointResponse.RefreshToken can be used to refresh the token and 
            // retrieve a correct access token

            return base.TokenResponseReceived(context);
        }
```

The access token starts with something like: `PAQABAAAAAAAm-06bl`...

It doesn't look like  a JWT token.

When I try to use the access token I get this error:

`CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217`

Here is the configuration for oidc:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, c =>
                {
                    c.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Forbidden";
                    // The default setting for cookie expiration is 14 days. SlidingExpiration is set to true by default
                    c.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
                    c.SlidingExpiration = true;
                })
                .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o =>
                {
                    o.ClientId = azureAdConfigs.ClientId;
                    o.ClientSecret = azureAdConfigs.ClientSecret;
                    o.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/";
                    o.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
                    o.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {ValidateIssuer = false};
                    o.Events = new MyAuthenticationEvents(_logger, Configuration);
                });
```

Down the authentication pipeline this method is called, setting the resource:

```
public override Task RedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectContext context)
        {
            context.Options.Resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
            return base.RedirectToIdentityProvider(context);
        }
```

My final goal is to obtain an access token from the oidc framework and use that token to make authorized calls to the microsoft graph api. Currently, I can only get the access token by using the refresh token and a call to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token to refresh access token.

Any ideas?

Comment: Chances are what you're getting back is a reference token? Is it local code or the graph API that's returning the `CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217` error?

Comment: The access token starts with something like: `PAQABAAAAAAAm-06bl`...

It doesn't look like  a JWT token.

The error is when I try to make a call to https://graph.microsoft.com/beta for any resource I try to retrieve

Comment: Are you still facing the issue?

Comment: I don't work on this anymore